# PySpark config through airflow

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to pass `packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.3` through `SparkSubmitOperator` to the config as described here:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/sql-data-sources-avro.html As I'm trying to use spark to read Avro files.

This is what I did in airflow dag, but it didn't work. Could someone please help to point out what I did wrong? Many thanks.

```
conf = Variable.get("spark_conf", deserialize_json = True)
conf_sp = conf.update({"spark.jars.packages":"org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.3"})
op = SparkSubmitOperator(
     application = "my_app",
     conf = conf_sp
     ....
     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SparkSubmitOperator` relies on the `SparkSubmitHook` which at the end composes a [`spark-submit` CLI command](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.3.2/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py#L253) to be executed.

In the CLI command form, you need to specify a dependency on packages with the package option so that they can be fetched from Maven and not in the configuration option.

```
op = SparkSubmitOperator(
     application = "my_app",
     packages = "org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.3"
)
```